# Antiforgerytoken in ajax post request ASP.NET MVC throwing 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having trouble with the AntiForgeryToken with ajax. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3. I tried the solution in jQuery Ajax calls and the Html.AntiForgeryToken(). Using that solution, the token is now being passed but I always get 500 (Internal Server Error), I have tried many solutions but I am not able reach its action method when using [ValidateAntiForgeryToken],

Here's my code:

```js
$("#headerNext").click(function () {
             var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
             var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

            $.ajax({
               // context: this,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Survey/LinkedSurveyAsJson",
                data: "{__RequestVerificationToken: "+ token + " ,id:'@Model.CustomerSurveyId',lang:'@(Model.Language == "ar" ? "ar" : "en")'}",
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                        $('#SurveyQuestions').html(templateQuestion(data));
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#headerText').hide();
                        $('#headerNext').hide();
                        $('#next').show();

                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    showErrorMessage(response.Message);
                    document.getElementById(bid).disabled = false;
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
 using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Survey", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            }
```

This is how action method looks like

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult LinkedSurveyAsJson(Guid? id, Guid? SurveyQuestionResponseId, Guid? LinkedSurveyQuestionId, Guid? SurveyQuestionId, Guid? SurveyId, string btnClicked, string ChoiceInputValue, string lang = "")
        { 
            CustomerSurveyViewModel customerSurvey = null;
return Json();
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30160504/6216322
The above link has the right answer to this question it worked for me.