# AJAX Generated button acts differently to pre-rendered button

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a web page with a partial view.
The partial view contains buttons to update the items.
Normally updating works fine. i.e. when the partial view is initially loaded as part of the page creation.

However I am now using AJAX to update the partial view. When I then click on the Ajax generated button within the partial view and try to update the item I get the error: The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted...

Looking at the data being sent, I noticed that the initially rendered buttons are sending a Set-Cookie header. and the updated AJAX generated buttons are not.

Looking at the generated HTML everything looks identical. But clearly the AJAX generated content is being treated differently to when it's pre-rendered

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788916/how-to-make-ajax-request-with-anti-forgery-token-in-mvc

Comment: I've tried that, but it hasn't helped. Also doesn't explain why a button generated via AJAX, work differently to a pre-rendered button. Despite them both having the same HTML.

Comment: make sure you dont have more than one anti-forgery token on your page.  particularly in your form

Comment: adding your view and partial view code would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out I missed a JavaScript lib when I was searching. it was using .on() on the original element which was being overwritten. It was then not triggering for the new buttons. set it to the body and everything is working now.