# MVC controller seems to be validating wrong AntiForgery token

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an AntiForgery token in the header of an Ajax request.  My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var tokenadr = $('form[action="/ServiceRequests/CreateRequest"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var token = tokenadr;
var headers = {};
var headersadr = {};
headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: headersadr,
    cache: false,
    url: "/ServiceRequests/CreateRequest",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formdata,
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        window.location = "/ServiceRequests/Details/" + response.id;
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
    },

})`
```

My form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRequest", "ServiceRequests", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "requestForm" })) 
   {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

The problem is that in my shared views folder, I have a partial login view with a form like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

So when I call my controller method using the Ajax code above, I get a server error.  My request does go through if I delete the AntiForgery token from my Account LogOff form (the token values are different for each form).  How can I resolve this without deleting my account logoff token?

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateRequest()
{
```

Here is what I have mainly been going by:  [How to make ajax request with anti-forgery token in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788916/how-to-make-ajax-request-with-anti-forgery-token-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.  Before my ajax call, I was serializing my whole form.  I changed:

```
var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
```

To this:

```
var other_data = $('#requestForm').serializeArray();
```

And now I am in business.